# Grails hasMany and belongs to comparison with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grails

We have seen in Burt Beckwith's presentation that Grails hasMany and belongsTo feature, which uses collections underneath, forces a large data set to load into memory to either check for uniqueness or to check for order.

My question is, do we have the same kind of issue in RoR as well if we use hasMany or belongsTo?

In other words, for the following example, in case of grails, all the post will be loaded into memory even if they are not accessed. How about RoR

```
class User{
   static hasMany = [posts:Post]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Rails has the same issue, but it has provided the methods `find_each` and `find_in_batches`, as described in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html to enable you to process a collection in whatever "batch size" you want.